# Opengl Game Loop Multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I have been messing around with OpenGL lately, and I noticed that the windows message pump is blocking whenever i attempt to resize my window, so as a result rendering is halted whenever i click on the menu bar or resize the window.

To fix this, I am looking into multithreading.

I have the following:

```
_beginthread(RenderEntryPoint, 0, 0);

while (!done)
{
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE);

    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}

void RenderEntryPoint(void *args)
{
    while (1)
    {
        //render code
    }
}
```

However, my scene isn't being rendered, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the OpenGL rendering context current in the rendering thread, **and** make sure it's not current in the windowing thread. This also means that you can't call *any* OpenGL functions from the windowing thread.